# Stripe File Links request - valid file id but object returns 0 file links with Reporting API

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am working on a Stripe API integration with the Reporting API. I have created a reporting run and can see there is a valid file id (a string that beings file_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).

However as I require downloading the CSV file I would expect there to be at least item in the `links.data` array? However as shown below it is empty as illustrated by `[]`

Why do I have a valid file but there doesn't appear to file link so I can download the file itself - I have valid successful payments and I have previously got data ok i'm just not sure why this is failing to return any links

```
{
    "id": "frr_1OgquWHpBAlTJ9LaTxa6aHXi",
    "object": "reporting.report_run",
    "created": 1707234612,
    "error": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "parameters": {
        "columns": [
            "automatic_payout_id",
            "balance_transaction_id",
            "created",
            "gross",
            "fee",
            "net",
            "description",
            "payment_metadata[saved_cart_id]"
        ],
        "interval_end": 1705881600,
        "interval_start": 1702944000
    },
    "report_type": "payout_reconciliation.itemized.5",
    "result": {
        "id": "file_1Ogoq6HpBAlTJ9LaPCdlRuW2",
        "object": "file",
        "created": 1707226650,
        "expires_at": 1738762650,
        "filename": "frr_1OgopUHpBAlTJ9La3AnmEGmt.csv",
        "links": {
            "object": "list",
            "data": [],
            "has_more": false,
            "url": "/v1/file_links?file=file_1Ogoq6HpBAlTJ9LaPCdlRuW2"
        },
        "purpose": "finance_report_run",
        "size": 1198,
        "title": "FinanceReportRun frr_1OgopUHpBAlTJ9La3AnmEGmt",
        "type": "csv",
        "url": "https://files.stripe.com/v1/files/file_1Ogoq6HpBAlTJ9LaPCdlRuW2/contents"
    },
    "status": "succeeded",
    "succeeded_at": 1707234612
}
```

Expected behaviour

```
        "links": {
            "object": "list",
            "data": [
             {
            "id": "link_1OgokVHpBAlTJ9LazTRUsoya",
            "object": "file_link",
            "created": 1707226303,
            "expired": false,
            "expires_at": null,
            "file": "file_1OglMqHpBAlTJ9LacjY9KRG7",
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {},
            "url": "https://files.stripe.com/links/MDB8YWNjdF8xT1A0clRIcEJBbFRKOUxhfGZsX3Rlc3RfQzlCc2lkbnlEOXl2NGY4NWlycWRSNDhB006jAtNgOL"
             },
            ],
            "has_more": false,
            "url": "/v1/file_links?file=file_1Ogoq6HpBAlTJ9LaPCdlRuW2"
        },
```

Actual behaviour

```
        "links": {
            "object": "list",
            "data": [
              // array is empty
            ],
            "has_more": false,
            "url": "/v1/file_links?file=file_1Ogoq6HpBAlTJ9LaPCdlRuW2"
        },
```

Comment: Are you seeing any associated links if you manually try listing the file links using this API? https://stripe.com/docs/api/file_links/list#list_file_links-file 

If not, I'd try reaching out to stripe support

Comment: Also, what happens if you try to create a file link manually? https://stripe.com/docs/api/file_links/create